# ui router is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying out following code for angular js, but not sure where I am getting wrong.
I have included ui-router and every required details. The states are defined for business and about us. Need help to find issue.

```js
  var formModule = angular.module("formModule",['ui.router']);

formModule.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', 
    function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider ){
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
       
       $stateProvider
               .state('business',{
                   url: '/business',
                   template: 'This is sample template',
               })
                .state('aboutus', {
                    url:'/aboutus',
                    template: '<div class="row" ng-controller="aboutUsController"><ul >      <li ng-repeat="director in directors">{{director.name}}</li>   </ul></div>',
                    controller: 'aboutUsController',
                });
               
    }]);


formModule.controller('aboutUsController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.directors = [{name: 'Avdhut Sonpethkar'},
                        {name: 'Sphurti Sonpethkar'},
                        {name: 'Pruthvi Sonpethkar'},];    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.1/angular.js"></script>



 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12">
                   <ul>
                       <li >
                           <a ui-sref=".business" >Business</a>
                       </li>
                       
                       <li >
                           <a ui-sref=".aboutus" >About us</a>
                       </li>
                       
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row"> 
               <div class="col-sm-12" ui-view>
                   
               </div>
           </div>
```

The code is correct as per my understanding but not sure where getting it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the '.' prefix in ui-sref

`<a ui-sref="business">Business</a>`

`<a ui-sref="aboutus">About us</a>`